# map function element-wise where function affects multiple elements

Tags: python, numpy, mapping, list-comprehension

I'm attempting to use 2 rows of an array to add large numbers, using each column of the array as a digit, then going element-wise through each column to determine if a 1 needs to be carried over.

I'm trying to employ a list comprehension along with a map in order to not have to iterate.  The issue I'm having is how to handle the syntax such that I can return both the current element and the next higher element (`x[y]` and `x[y+1]`):

```
targdigit = 1000
ind = 2
n = np.zeros((3,targdigit + 1))

def adder(intup):
    global targdigit, ind
    x = intup[0]
    y = intup[1]
    ind +=1
    if y == targdigit - 1 and x[y] > 0:
        print('targ index is ' + str(ind))
        sys.exit()
    if x[y] >= 10:
        x[y] %= 10
        x[y+1] += 1
    return x

for i in range (2):
    n[i][0] = 1

while True:
    n[2] = n[0] + n[1]
    n[2] = np.array([adder((n[2], xi)) for xi in range(n.shape[1])])
    n[0], n[1] = n[1], n[2]
```

What is the appropriate syntax for the map and the return statement (and perhaps function arguments?) to apply both changes to `x[y]` and `x[y+1]`?

Comment: With iteration like this, there's no advantage to using `numpy`.  Iterating on lists is faster.  List comprehension and `map` are convenient ways of writing certain types of `for` loops, namely ones that use list append.  But don't stand on you head trying to avoid for loops; the alternatives aren't much faster.

Comment: Thanks, @hpaulj.  I'm always trying to learn more "pythonic" ways to do things, mainly for future implementations of a similar concept.